# Excel copy-paste range on specific sheet according to cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, worksheet

I have a workbook with a master sheet called "NIR" containing the following data: Column **A** contains product names(the same as the rest of the worksheets names);Column **B** contains quantity and Column **C** contains prices.

I want to create a VBA to search in my master sheet "NIR" in Column A and copy Columns B and C to  specific sheets according to master sheet "NIR" ,cells in Column A.

Example:

```
Sheet "NIR"
A3="shoes"
A4="pants"
B3 = 3 (pairs)
C3 = 10 (price)
```

copy **B3** and **C3** to sheets "shoes" and "pants"according to Sheet"NIR" **A3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim LastRowNIR As Long, i As Long, LastRowWs As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NIR")
        'Find the last row of column A
         LastRowNIR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
         'Import all data in an array starting from A1 to C last row
         arr = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowNIR)
         'Loop array
         For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arr(i, 1))
                'Find the last row of column B
                LastRowWs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                'Write in the next available row the quantity
                .Range("B" & LastRowWs + 1).Value = arr(i, 2)
                'Write in the next available row the prices
                .Range("C" & LastRowWs + 1).Value = arr(i, 3)
            End With
            
         Next i
         
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: it works,values are good and it pasted to the correct sheets.Just 1 small problem,it pasted on the bottom of the table.I forgot to specify that table header is present on Row 1 and 2 , data should be pasted starting with Row 3.Can you please tell me what I need to correct in this formula?thank you very much!

Comment: So, every time you will add in row 3?

Comment: Replace `arr = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowNIR)` with `arr = .Range("A3:C" & LastRowNIR)`

Comment: I tried but it still pastes on the bottom of the table

Comment: `LastRowWs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                'Write in the next available row the quantity
                .Range("B" & LastRowWs + 1).Value = arr(i, 2)` Is it possible to change something to `.End(xlDown).` or play with offset values?

Comment: or is it possible to insert `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` somewhere in this code?

Comment: problem is present only on formated tables.Otherwise the VBA code works fine.

Comment: could you please upload a photo?